# Instance and Static Methods in Java

Tags: java, static, instance

I have a Doubt and i can't find it on google or on Youtube, so I am Asking here.

As we know,
Instance methods can call other Instance Methods directly without objects in the same class. However we need objects to call Instance method in a Static method.

I want to ask why is it so? How does Instance method calls other instance method directly without object but need an object to get called inside a Static method?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Basically you need to learn about `Object Oriented` programming concept and then you can answer yourself easily, answering to this question means teaching a semi-complete course.

Answer (score 0):

Because instance methods already have the object.  You can access it with the `this` keyword.  When you call an instance method in an instance method, it calls it on `this` unless you specifically call it on another instance.  In a static method you don't have an object, so there is no `this` object to call it on.  So unless you specify an instance there's no default to call it on.

Why doesn't the language force you to call it on `this` rather than assume?  Convenience, it allows you to type a bit less.  Its a common feature in other object oriented languages as well.  There are languages that won't do it and require you to specify the object at all times.

Comment: Sorry i can't get the concept of "this" here, can your provide me a link so i understand its concept and then understand your answer.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: Basically, this is a reference who's value is the object an instance method is being called on.  In static methods, this doesn't exist and using it is a syntax error.

Comment: How does Instance methods already have object if i haven't created one?

Comment: Because somewhere else created one.  Otherwise the first instance method couldn't have been called, since instance methods can only be called on instances.